# Watch ruby files, run it when modified, and stop it when

Tags: ruby

I want to write a file watcher which will run any modified ruby file asynchronously.

Here are the rules:

1. **Run a modified ruby file asynchronously**: watch files in a specific folder; if any `.rb` file is modified, run that `.rb` file asynchronously and keep watching files.
2. **Cancellable async jobs**: during running a `.rb` file triggered in step 1, if a `.stop` file is modified, stop running the corresponding `.rb` file.
3. **Queue-able async jobs**: during running a `.rb` file triggered in step 1, if any watched ruby file is modified, run that new modified ruby file after finishing current ruby file; if there are multiple watched ruby files are modified, only run the latest one.

For example, if the folder contains the following files:

```
-- path_to_folder/
    |- a.rb
    |- a.stop
    |- b.rb
    |- b.stop
    |- c.rb
    |- c.stop
```

Cases:

1. `a.rb` is modified, then

   - run `a.rb` asynchronously which is a heavy job
2. during `a.rb` is running, and when `b.rb` is modified, then

   - schedule to run `b.rb` asynchronously after `a.rb` is finished.
3. during `a.rb` is running and `b.rb` is scheduled to run, and when `c.rb` is modified, then

   - cancel scheduling to run `b.rb`;
   - schedule to run `c.rb` asynchronously after `a.rb` is finished.
4. during `a.rb` is running and `c.rb` is scheduled to run, and when `a.stop` is modified, then

   - cancel running `a.rb` immediately
   - start to run `c.rb` (the latest modified ruby file)

I know how to watch the files and run it synchronously:

```rb
require 'filewatcher'

Filewatcher.new("path_to_folder/").watch do |changes|
  # run the ruby file synchronously
  if File.extname(changes) == ".rb"
    system("ruby #{changes}")
  end

end
```

but I have no idea how to run it asynchronously (not blocking the file watcher and keep watching), cancel it if needed, and schedule the next runner for the latest changes.

Comment: Look into the [Thread](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Thread.html) class, specifically the `kill` and `alive?` methods

Comment: I suppose the `listen` gem https://github.com/guard/listen can help you to achieve your goals. If not all, then at least some.

Comment: @maxpleaner I tried `Thread`, and it almost did the job, except that it doesn't really stop the shell task immediately inside the thread when I use `Thread.kill()`. The async task will invoke shell commands to run tests for my project.

Comment: @XareeLee did you resolve this? Were you able to get Filewatcher working asynchronously?